# batch "replace into" for CodeIgniter Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

CodeIgniter offers a great function to update in batch called `update_batch()`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch

It also offers a function `replace()` to execute `replace into` mysql queries

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=replace#CI_DB_query_builder::replace

Is there any way to have something like `replace_batch()` or equivalent? I am using a loop with a replace inside, but figured a function would be better

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clone [my repository](https://github.com/woodcockjosh/CodeIgniter) I have implemented. [I tried](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/4768) to get the solution into the main branch but it seems like narfbg is adamantly against it. Maybe some more participation from the community could get it implemented.

```
/**
 * Replace_Batch
 *
 * Compiles batch insert strings replacing any existing rows and runs the queries
 *
 * @param   string  $table  Table to replace insert into
 * @param   array   $set    An associative array of insert values
 * @param   bool    $escape Whether to escape values and identifiers
 * @return  int Number of rows inserted or FALSE on failure
 */
public function replace_batch($table, $set = NULL, $escape = NULL, $batch_size = 100)
{
    if ($set === NULL)
    {
        if (empty($this->qb_set))
        {
            return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_use_set') : FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (empty($set))
        {
            return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('replace_batch() called with no data') : FALSE;
        }

        $this->set_insert_batch($set, '', $escape);
    }

    if (strlen($table) === 0)
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->qb_from[0]))
        {
            return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_set_table') : FALSE;
        }

        $table = $this->qb_from[0];
    }

    // Batch this baby
    $affected_rows = 0;
    for ($i = 0, $total = count($this->qb_set); $i < $total; $i += $batch_size)
    {
        if ($this->query($this->_replace_batch($this->protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, $escape, FALSE), $this->qb_keys, array_slice($this->qb_set, $i, $batch_size))))
        {
            $affected_rows += $this->affected_rows();
        }
    }

    $this->_reset_write();
    return $affected_rows;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Replace batch statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific insert string from the supplied data.
 *
 * @param   string  $table  Table name
 * @param   array   $keys   INSERT keys
 * @param   array   $values INSERT values
 * @return  string
 */
protected function _replace_batch($table, $keys, $values)
{
    return 'REPLACE INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES '.implode(', ', $values);
}
```

Above is the exact same code as on Github just so the solution is indexable back to stackoverflow.com. But unfortunately my reply on stackoverflow is limited to 30k characters so I cannot paste in the entire commit which also includes changes to db drivers.

Comment: I've read your commit...and I think that idea is acceptable. When a thing is not widely used, they wont patch it. like my issue https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4719