# Online exam scores duplicating after two or more saves

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a school web app that has an online exam feature. Students are given a number of times they can attempt the exam.

However, when a student attempts the exam two or more times and saves, the scores are duplicated in the database instead of being updated.

I will like that when a student attempts an exam again, the previous scores are overwritten not duplicated.

[image: duplicated scores]

Controller:

```
 public function save()
    {
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
            $total_rows = $this->input->post('total_rows');
            if (!empty($total_rows)) {
                $save_result = array();
                foreach ($total_rows as $row_key => $row_value) {

                    if (isset($_POST['radio' . $row_value])) {
                        $save_result[] = array(
                            'onlineexam_student_id'  => $this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'),
                            'onlineexam_question_id' => $this->input->post('question_id_' . $row_value),
                            'select_option'          => $_POST['radio' . $row_value],
                        );
                    }
                }
                $this->onlineexamresult_model->add($save_result);
                redirect('user/onlineexam', 'refresh');
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Model:

```
 public function add($data_insert)
    {

        $this->db->trans_begin();

        if (!empty($data_insert)) {

            $this->db->insert_batch('onlineexam_student_results', $data_insert);
        }

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="exambgtop">
                        <h3><?php echo $exam->exam; ?></h3>
                        <div class="exambgright">
                            <div id="box_header" class="inlineblock"></div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm save_exam_btn"><?php echo $this->lang->line('submit') ?> </button>
                        </div>
```

Comment: please show us your view part also..

Comment: Looks like you want to "batch replace into" ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645278/batch-replace-into-for-codeigniter-active-record  (there is no need to show the View file ...well, actually `'question_id_' . $row_value` indicates that you are not properly declaring field `name`s with array syntax)

Comment: @KUMAR I have included the view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go...

Controller:

```
public function save()
{
    $total_rows = $this->input->post('total_rows');
    if (empty($total_rows)) {
        redirect('user/onlineexam');
    }

    foreach ($total_rows as $row_value) {
        if ($this->input->post('radio' . $row_value) === null) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $this->onlineexamresult_model->answer(
            (int) $this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'),
            (int) $this->input->post('question_id_' . $row_value),
            $this->input->post('radio' . $row_value)
        );
    }
    
    redirect('user/onlineexam');
}
```

Model:

```
public function answer(int $student_id, int $question_id, string $answer)
{
    // Check if the student has previously answered the question
    $current_answer = $this->get_answer_by_student_id($student_id, $question_id);
    
    if (empty($current_answer)) {
        return $this->db->insert('onlineexam_student_results', [
            'onlineexam_student_id' => $student_id,
            'onlineexam_question_id' => $question_id,
            'select_option' => $answer,
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }
    
    return $this->db->update('onlineexam_student_results', [
        'select_option' => $answer,
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ], [
        'onlineexam_student_id' => $student_id,
        'onlineexam_question_id' => $question_id
    ]);
}

public function get_answer_by_student_id(int $student_id, int $question_id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('onlineexam_student_results', [
        'onlineexam_student_id' => $student_id,
        'onlineexam_question_id' => $question_id
    ])->row_array();
}
```

Comment: "Try this" (Give this a go) answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.